# POST http://localhost:3000/api/login 504 (Gateway Timeout)

Tags: express, proxy, create-react-app

I am using create react app with express backend . I am getting gateway timeout due to proxy issue . How do i fix it?I am using cra-2 so proxy has changed in cra2 and I get this error sometime but not all the time , is it only in development or is it going to happen in production also?

Comment: Check out your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832389/what-can-i-do-to-fix-a-504-gateway-timeout-error